# "Fake" scene with a lot of lights (e.g. a city in night)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

For example, a scene like this in real life has thousands of light sources:

[image]

I'd imagine it's so expensive that a normal PC can't render it. Is there a way to this kind of scene without actually having thousands of lamps/emission materials? Maybe some kind of screen space/baking tricks? (preferable in Cycles, but if EEVEE works for this I'd like to know as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I assume you know the obvious way, which is to have someone go to the scene and create an HDRI that you then use as your world shader with a setup like this:

[image: Simple world shader using HDRI]

where the mapping node is only used to rotate Z so as to position the HDRI where you want it with respect to the camera's view.

2. You can create such a scene once, and render it as a 360 degree panorama, creating your own HDRI to use in the world shader.
3. You can use a technique I first learned from three of Ian Hubert's "[Lazy Tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4Dq5VyfewIxxjzS34k2NES_PuDUIjRcY)" YouTube series.  You can find these as

   - [Apocalyptic Cities](https://youtu.be/qNba2oEij2c)
   - [Modeling Buildings](https://youtu.be/v_ikG-u_6r0)
   - [Make Cities](https://youtu.be/JjnyapZ_P-g)

The gist of Hubert's technique is
- Use images of building fronts rather than model the buildings
- Use loop cuts to create polygons where windows should be
- Use an emitter material for the 'windows' and an image texture for the building.

This technique dramatically reduces the number of objects you have to create, reducing scene complexity to the point where you can get reasonable render times.